# How to decrypt on frontend which is encrypted on backend using crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

Data is encrypted with the below code, is there any option to decrypt on the front-end if know the key and iv?

```
const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr'; 
 // const algorithm = 'aes-128-cbc';
 let inVec = crypto.randomBytes(16);
 const secret = 'salted';
 const key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(String(secret)).digest('base64').substr(0, 32);
 const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, key.substr(0, 16))
 let encrypt = cipher.update(name, 'utf8', 'base64')
 encrypt = encrypt + cipher.final();
```

Comment: Yes it is. Post your decryption code for further assistance.

Comment: Note that using the key (or part of it) as IV is a particularly for CTR serious vulnerability, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2991). Instead, for each encryption a random IV should be applied (such as `inVec`, which is not used anywhere).

Comment: @Topaco Sorry I don't have decryption code, Do you suggestion for frontend javascript package.

Comment: This is a simple encryption with AES-256 in CTR mode and SHA-256 as key derivation function. Every major JavaScript crypto library supports this, e.g. WebCrypto API, CryptoJS etc. see [here](https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441#file-js-crypto-libraries-md).

Comment: If you need to send the key and IV to the frontend along with the encrypted data, then encryption provides no security, just hassle. In other words, increasing (or reducing) the algorithm strength or key length has no effect on an attacker's ability to read the encrypted data. They will use whatever you sent them, so might as well do the decryption server side (or not encrypting at all, depending on the backend use case).

Comment: Always start the analysis of what you need by realizing that you should have TLS to secure the link between client and server. You have to go out of your what to not have that in place. Now, why do you think you need *more* than that?